# single result from a query with group by

Tags: mysql, select

Please help me to write this query.

I want to get all Words for which the last repetition for a given user has a date earlier than today OR there is no repetition.

I have something like this, but it's incorrect.

```
SELECT * FROM `Word` w LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM `Repetition`
    GROUP BY word_id
    ORDER BY next DESC
) r ON w.id = r.word_id 
WHERE wordset_id = 1 AND (r.user_id IS NULL) OR r.next < CURRENT_DATE
```

"Subquery" should return a table of last repetition for a  given user/word combination

I want to get: All words that don't have any repetitions or have due ( meaning earlier or today) repetitions (both for a given user)

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand the problem completely, but to word it differently, you're wanting to return all of the words that don't have repetitions today?

```
SELECT * FROM word
WHERE word_id NOT IN (
   SELECT word_id FROM repetition WHERE next >= CURRENT_DATE
)
```

Something like that or am I way off?  Not really sure what you're trying to do with wordset_id or user_id there.

Comment: All words that don't have any repetitions or have due (due meaning earlier or today) repetitions (both for a given user)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `Word` w LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT word_id, user_id, `repNo`, `repCount`, `date`, `ef`,  MAX(next) next 
 FROM `Repetition` GROUP BY `word_id`,`user_id`) r ON w.id = r.word_id 
WHERE wordset_id = 1 AND (r.user_id IS NULL) OR r.next < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to write it in DQL?

Comment: It may seem to work, but it is possible that values of repNo, repCount, date and ef will be incorrect. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to get, all user/word combinations or just words for one, given user?

Comment: All words that don't have any repetitions or have due ( meaning earlier or today) repetitions (both for a given user)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use subquery here, you'll should be fine just with join;

```
SELECT words.*
FROM words
-- Left join makes sure that you get one result for each word
LEFT JOIN Repetition ON (
    (Words.id = Repetition.word_id)
    -- Get just one user's result
    AND (Repetition.user_id = ?)
)
-- And filter today's results:
WHERE (Repetition.id IS NULL) OR (Repetition.next < NOW())
GROUP BY Words.id
```